# usando SqlServerEsxpress Local DB puede haber conexiones a mi BD en red?

Tags: sql-server-express

Quisiera saber si usando esta versión de SQL mi aplicación en C# puede conectarse a la BD, para esto la BD estará en un servidor y la aplicación en equipos en red.

Comment: Hola Sandro Joel Ramos Saravia, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede utilizar esta versión (SQLSERVER EXPRESS LOCALDB) para conexiones remotas, según estas referencias:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1694526-access-localdb-from-local-area-network
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely